# About azure tags and policies

Tags: azure, tags, policy

I want to add tag to every new resource that gets created in my azure subscription automatically. I want that tag to be ------ id - "createdby" and value - "id of associate or name of that associate who is creatinf that resource"

Is that possible in microsoft azure?

Comment: I think this blog could meet your requirement : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/tagging-azure-resources-with-a-creator/ba-p/1479819

Comment: thanks for the link @StanleyGong - It really helped

Comment: Hi @Shubhi Sharma , thanks for your reply,glad to know this is helpful. I have summarized it as an answer. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in Azure, but for this requirement, it is not possible if you just use Azure policy. Here is a solution that could meet your requirement provided by Microsoft engineer which uses Azure Function and Azure policy. For details see [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/tagging-azure-resources-with-a-creator/ba-p/1479819).